# How can I run some code when a SilverLight OOB Application is uninstalled?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

Is there any way to add some code to fire when an OOB silverlight app is uninstalled?
I would like to fire something to my webservice when a user uninstalls the app, is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out that you can handle the "InstallStateChanged" event on the App.xaml. With this you can check the InstallState and do something based on that.

Comment: That setting is not actually for determining when the app has been **un** installed.... think about it: how can your Silverlight code run (and fire something to a webservice) when it has been uninstalled?

Comment: Quote: [The InstallState will tell us if the current application has been *installed*.](http://chris.59north.com/post/Silverlight-4-COM-interope280a6I-cane28099t-believe-I-am-excitede280a6.aspx)

Comment: I should have said, whilst uninstalling then, not when uninstalled. But the above will work whilst uninstalling and return the Enum "NotInstalled", therefore enabling me to fire something to my webservice.